# FSM 2 process VHDL

Tags: vhdl, fpga, fsm

I was attempting to write down the VHDL code for the FSM of a control unit of a my project. I chose the 2 process way with one process for the state register and the other process for the next state and output logic. Anyway I'm having some problems in setting up the solution as some signals give synthesis latch warning (I know why they appear). The only solution I found (without using one single process for both state register and output logic and without adding 3 more states) was to add some output logic in the process that manages the state logic.

With much surprise it works but is this conceptually correct? I mean, is it correct to dirty the code of the state register process with some output logic or am I breaking the 2 process pattern?

This is the code of my working and "latch-free warning" control unit. Anyway the latch involved the signal `sel_mode` as I don't know how to specify in the else branch of the state IDLE something like "keep the previous value of "sel_mode"(without having the latch warning).

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
entity control_unit is
Port ( clock : in  STD_LOGIC;
       reset_n_in : in  STD_LOGIC;
       primo_operando : in  STD_LOGIC;
       secondo_operando : in  STD_LOGIC;
       add_sub : in  STD_LOGIC;
          ov : in STD_LOGIC;
          subtract_in : in STD_LOGIC;
          led_ov : out STD_LOGIC;
          reset_n_out : out STD_LOGIC;
       subtract_out : out  STD_LOGIC;
          en_w_primo_op : out STD_LOGIC;
          en_w_secondo_op : out STD_LOGIC;
          en_w_risultato : out STD_LOGIC;
          sel_mode : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0)
          );
end control_unit;

architecture Behavioral of control_unit is

type state is (IDLE, PRIMO_OP, SECONDO_OP, RISULTATO);
signal curr, nxt : state := IDLE;

begin

change_state : process(clock, reset_n_in)
begin
    if reset_n_in = '0' then
        curr <= IDLE;
-- in the following lines I mix the state register logic with output logic
    elsif rising_edge(clock) then
        if curr = PRIMO_OP then
            sel_mode <= "10";
        elsif curr = SECONDO_OP then
            sel_mode <= "01";
        elsif curr = RISULTATO then
            sel_mode <= "00";
        end if;
        curr <= nxt;
    end if;
end process;

fsm: process(curr, reset_n_in, primo_operando, secondo_operando, add_sub)
begin
    if reset_n_in = '0' then
        reset_n_out <= '0';
    else
        reset_n_out <= '1';
    end if;
    en_w_primo_op <= '0';
    en_w_secondo_op <= '0';
    en_w_risultato <= '0';
    case curr is
        when IDLE =>
            if primo_operando = '1' then
             --   sel_mode <= "10";
                nxt <= PRIMO_OP;
            elsif secondo_operando = '1' then
             -- sel_mode <= "01";
                nxt <= SECONDO_OP;
            elsif add_sub = '1' then
             -- sel_mode <= "00";
                nxt <= RISULTATO;
            else
                nxt <= IDLE;
             -- how to specify keep sel_mode to the previous value??
            end if;
        when PRIMO_OP =>
         -- sel_mode <= "10";
            en_w_primo_op <= '1';
            nxt <= IDLE;
        when SECONDO_OP =>
         -- sel_mode <= "01";
            en_w_secondo_op <= '1';
            nxt <= IDLE;
        when RISULTATO =>
         -- sel_mode <= "00";
            en_w_risultato <= '1';
            nxt <= IDLE;
    end case;
end process;

led_ov <= ov;
subtract_out <= subtract_in;

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: ***With much surprise it works but is this conceptually correct? I mean, is it correct to dirty the code of the state register process with some output logic or am I breaking the 2 process pattern?*** Do you have a programming question, or is this all about style?  What happens if `sel_mode` isn't valid until the first branch from IDLE?  (And synthesized to a binary representation before mapping the default value for `sel_mode` is likely "00"). Are you simulating your design?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Added**:

> With much surprise it works but is this conceptually correct? I mean, is it correct to dirty the code of the state register process with some output logic or am I breaking the 2 process pattern?

The state of your design is always made up of *all* registers in your design, not just the register `curr` in your design. You can think of it this way:

- The (partial) state of the FSM is defined by `curr`. This is described using the two-process form.
- The register `sel_mode` in your posted code is a data-path register, and thus, defines the state of the data-path part. You have described it using the one-process form. An alternate solution using the two-process form, I will describe below.

---

> Anyway the latch involved the signal "sel_mode" as I don't know how to specify in the else branch of the state IDLE something like "keep the previous value of "sel_mode"(without having the latch warning).

To prevent the inference of a latch, you have to save the current value of sel_mode into a clock-edge triggered register and assign the register value whenever you want to output the previous value. As the register represents the previous value, I called it `sel_mode_prev`. The assignment of the register takes place in the clocked process together with some reset logic:

```
change_state : process(clock, reset_n_in)
begin
    if reset_n_in = '0' then
        curr <= IDLE;
        sel_mode_prev <= "00"; -- or some other value
    elsif rising_edge(clock) then
        curr <= nxt;
        sel_mode_prev <= sel_mode_i; -- save current value
    end if;
end process;
```

The output `sel_mode` is assigned in the combinational part. But, as you cannot read the value of an output in the assignment of `sel_mode_prev` above, you have to assign the desired value for `sel_mode` to an intermediate value, which I called `sel_mode_i`. The combinational process `fsm` then assigns this signal. The assignment of the output `sel_mode <= sel_mode_i;` is done combinational below the process together with other output assignments.

Here, is the complete modified architecture with comments:

```
architecture Behavioral of control_unit is

type state is (IDLE, PRIMO_OP, SECONDO_OP, RISULTATO);
signal curr, nxt : state := IDLE;

signal sel_mode_i    : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0); -- internal version of output
signal sel_mode_prev : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0); -- previous version of sel_mode

begin

change_state : process(clock, reset_n_in)
begin
    if reset_n_in = '0' then
        curr <= IDLE;
        sel_mode_prev <= "00"; -- or some other value
    elsif rising_edge(clock) then
        curr <= nxt;
        sel_mode_prev <= sel_mode_i; -- save current value
    end if;
end process;

fsm: process(curr, reset_n_in, primo_operando, secondo_operando, add_sub,
             sel_mode_prev) -- also add sel_mode_prev here
begin
    if reset_n_in = '0' then
        reset_n_out <= '0';
    else
        reset_n_out <= '1';
    end if;
    en_w_primo_op <= '0';
    en_w_secondo_op <= '0';
    en_w_risultato <= '0';
    case curr is
        when IDLE =>
            if primo_operando = '1' then
                sel_mode_i <= "10"; -- assign internal signal
                nxt <= PRIMO_OP;
            elsif secondo_operando = '1' then
                sel_mode_i <= "01"; -- assign internal signal
                nxt <= SECONDO_OP;
            elsif add_sub = '1' then
                sel_mode_i <= "00"; -- assign internal signal
                nxt <= RISULTATO;
            else
                sel_mode_i <= sel_mode_prev; -- output old value at default
                nxt <= IDLE;
            end if;
        when PRIMO_OP =>
            sel_mode_i <= "10"; -- assign internal signal
            en_w_primo_op <= '1';
            nxt <= IDLE;
        when SECONDO_OP =>
            sel_mode_i <= "01"; -- assign internal signal
            en_w_secondo_op <= '1';
            nxt <= IDLE;
        when RISULTATO =>
            sel_mode_i <= "00"; -- assign internal signal
            en_w_risultato <= '1';
            nxt <= IDLE;
    end case;
end process;

sel_mode <= sel_mode_i; -- assign internal signal to output
led_ov <= ov;
subtract_out <= subtract_in;

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Thank you Martin. So is the solution I found wrong?

Comment: @Mazzola No, your solution is right as long as `sel_mode` matches your specification. You just mixed code patterns. I have extended my answer to discuss this point.